# Let's get critical: Dec 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Aviation Stack Exchange](http://aviation.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What happens when a pilot has no Instrument Rating and visibility drops?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9764/what-happens-when-a-pilot-has-no-instrument-rating-and-visibility-drops)

**Net Score: 18** (Excellent: 19, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What do they use to de-ice aircraft and runways on snowy days?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9436/what-do-they-use-to-de-ice-aircraft-and-runways-on-snowy-days)

**Net Score: 17** (Excellent: 20, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How are evolution and variants of aircraft considered by certification authorities?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/how-evolution-and-variants-of-aircrafts-are-considered-by-certification-authorit)

**Net Score: 17** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the cable connected to a plane for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/what-is-the-cable-connected-to-a-plane-for)

**Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can landing in zero visibility be safe?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/landing-with-zero-visibility)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How fast can an F-22 scramble?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9703/how-fast-can-an-f-22-scramble)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Where to find a waypoints/fixed points, navaids, airports database](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/where-to-find-a-waypoints-fixed-points-navaids-airports-database)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are there ever temporary flight corridors?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/are-there-ever-temporary-flight-corridors)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the true formula for parasite drag?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/what-is-the-true-formula-for-parasite-drag)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [In which countries a medically unfit US pilot can fly?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9643/in-which-countries-a-medically-unfit-us-pilot-can-fly)

**Net Score: -10** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 13)

---

Answer (score 9):

Just to share my thought, all question that is well thought is well answered. Members here are professional in both their job and their part of community. Maybe grammar error is common but that is also everywhere even among english speaking country. As for the site's stat, low question rating is because aviation is SO precise that one question need to be asked once. A repeated asking would trigger 'duplicate' flag immediately. We don't have luxury of so many different environment to operate compare with serverfault or other sites (thank god!!)

For me the site is in the good track.